# ko.js: Add data to existing vm

Tags: javascript, object, knockout.js

Assume the following situation:

```
self.watchedRecords = ko.observableArray();

//Get watchlist entries from server
dataService.getWatched().then(function (resolve) {
    //Push all items to the observable array
    self.watchedRecords(resolve.entries); 
});
```

In my `resolve` I have another key, `likes`, which contains the information (as an array of course) about which entries were liked by the logged in user:

```
{
    watchedItemGuid: 572, //user liked item in which the guid is 572
    id: 3 //the like is saved in another table as item with the id 3
}
```

I try to add the information about liked or not to the `watchedRecords` observable, to use it later (for deleting the like for example).

I'm not sure if looping over the likes and filtering the original data is a good approach. Is there a best practice about this topic?

Comment: Your service could return the likes merged with the entries array.  Each entrie will has one more field,of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start out by implementing a way to combine the list of `likes` and `entries`. Without performance optimization or architectural influences, this could be something along the lines of:

- Map over your `entries`
- Add a `liked` property to the existing object received from the server
- Determine its value (`true` or `false`) by looping over your `likes`

In the snippet below you'll see this implementation which is quite hard to read, and slow once your lists grow *(`O(n*m)` I believe... but don't quote me on that)*

```js
var watchedRecords = ko.observableArray([]);

var setWatchedRecords = function(resolve) {
  watchedRecords(
    // Map over the entries, this is our base set of data
    resolve.entries.map(
      function(record) {
        // Add one property toeach entry: "liked"
        return Object.assign(record, {
          // The value is liked is determined by our array
          // of liked items.
          liked: resolve.likes.some(function(like) {
             // If some like contains our record id, we return true
             return like.watchedItemId === record.id;
          })
        })
      }
    )
  );
};

setWatchedRecords(getWatched());
console.log(watchedRecords().map(JSON.stringify));


// Mock data
function getEntries() {
  return [ { id: 572, name: "Entry 2" }, { id: 573, name: "Entry 3" }, { id: 574, name: "Entry 4" }, { id: 575, name: "Entry 5" }, { id: 576, name: "Entry 6" } ]
};

function getLikes() {
  return [ { watchedItemId: 572, id: 1 }, { watchedItemId: 576, id: 2 } ];
};

function getWatched() {
  return { entries: getEntries(), likes: getLikes() };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Initial optimizations I'd personally make (switching to ES2015 syntax):

- Use a `Set` to store all `liked` ids (so you'll only have to loop through them once)
- Cut up your functions in to some single purpose ones.

```js
var get = key => obj => obj[key];

var watchedRecords = ko.observableArray([]);

var getLikedIds = (resolve) => new Set(
  resolve.likes.map(get("watchedItemId"))
);

var getWatchedRecords = (resolve) => {
  var likes = getLikedIds(resolve);
  
  return resolve.entries.map(
    e => Object.assign(e, { liked: likes.has(e.id) })
  );
};

watchedRecords(getWatchedRecords(getWatched()));
console.log(watchedRecords().map(JSON.stringify));


// Mock data
function getEntries() {
  return [ { id: 572, name: "Entry 2" }, { id: 573, name: "Entry 3" }, { id: 574, name: "Entry 4" }, { id: 575, name: "Entry 5" }, { id: 576, name: "Entry 6" } ]
};

function getLikes() {
  return [ { watchedItemId: 572, id: 1 }, { watchedItemId: 576, id: 2 } ];
};

function getWatched() {
  return { entries: getEntries(), likes: getLikes() };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Now, the last problem to solve is whether you want to re-use your viewmodels. Currently, your array of items gets completely replaced on every update. If knockout has to render a list or do some other computations, it might be worth it to add some complexity to gain performance... For example:

- Create a `Record` viewmodel that can be instantiated with an `id`, an `entry` and whether it is `liked`
- When new data is received, look up the existing viewmodel

  - If there is one: update its `liked` status
  - If there is no viewmodel: create a new one and add it to your collection

Edit: for fun, I included this as an example as well:

```js
var Record = function(data, likeMap) {
  Object.assign(this, data);
  
  // Each `Record` instance has a reference to the
  // manager's `Set` of liked ids. Now, we can
  // compute whether we're a liked Record automatically!
  this.liked = ko.pureComputed(
    () => likeMap().has(this.id)
  );
  
  this.toString = () => "Id: " + this.id + ", liked: " + this.liked();
};

var RecordManager = function() {
  const likes = ko.observable(new Set());
  const recordMap = ko.observable(new Map());
  
  // Our record viewmodels in a list
  this.records = ko.pureComputed(
    () => Array.from(recordMap().values())
  ).extend({ "deferred": true });
  
  // This takes your server side likes and transforms
  // it to a set of liked ids
  const setLikes = likeData => {
    likes(
      new Set(likeData.map(get("watchedItemId")))
    );
  };
  
  // This takes your server side records and transforms
  // them to a Map of `id: Record`
  const setRecords = recordData => {
    recordMap(
      recordData.reduce(
        // Re-use our previously createdviewmodel if there is any
        (map, r) => map.set(r.id, recordMap().get(r.id) || new Record(r, likes))
      , new Map())
    );
  };
  
  // Updating is now independent of order.
  // Our Record instances contain a reference to the `likes` set,
  // thereby automatically updating their like status
  this.updateRecords = data => {
    setRecords(data.entries);
    setLikes(data.likes);
  }
};

var rm = new RecordManager();

rm.updateRecords(getWatched());

console.log(rm.records().map(r => r.toString()));


// Mock data
function getEntries() {
  return [ { id: 572, name: "Entry 2" }, { id: 573, name: "Entry 3" }, { id: 574, name: "Entry 4" }, { id: 575, name: "Entry 5" }, { id: 576, name: "Entry 6" } ]
};

function getLikes() {
  return [ { watchedItemId: 572, id: 1 }, { watchedItemId: 576, id: 2 } ];
};

function getWatched() {
  return { entries: getEntries(), likes: getLikes() };
};

// Utils
function get(key) { return function(obj) { return obj[key]; }; };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks for explaining. +1 also for ES6

Comment: Happy to help. I've included a third snippet that shows how you can implement those re-used viewmodels. It's kind of personal in terms of "style", but might be worth having a look at!